# Writing the contents of an array to a string

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a two-dimensional character array `board[row][col]`, which is designed to simulate a game board for a game of Xs and Os. (For reference, each element in the array is either an X, an O, or ' ', a space to signify no move in that square.)

I am trying to get a string of all characters in the array, row by row. That is, the first row will be printed to string, then the second row will be appended to that string, until all rows are traversed. In the end, the result should look like a string of symbols such as "XXO X OOX" for this game board:

```
X X O
  X  
O O X
```

How can this be done?

Comment: @djechlin lol +1 you were 3 seconds faster. :P

Comment: I've tried to do nested for loops, but I found it tough to put each char into the string one by one. (I'm kind of new to this.) Do I get the element from the array position, and convert that char to a string before adding it to the full string?

Comment: Use [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
 for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
   str.append(board[i][j]);
```

you could find more data about `StringBuilder` [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

Comment: OP doesn't want newline the output should be `XXO X OOX` so we should add a space

Answer (score 2):

I think better sulution  will be like this

```
        char [][] board = new char[][]{{'x','x','o',},{'x',},{'o','o','x',}};

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        for (char[] aBoard : board) 
            builder.append(String.valueOf(aBoard)).append(" ");

       System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

out

```
xxo x oox
```

Comment: @elyashiv I know, and this solution better, because faster

Answer (score 1):

You can try something along these lines:

```
char[][] board = {{'X', 'O', 'X'}, {0, 'O', 0}, {'X', 'O', 'X'}};

String s = "";
for (char[] row : board) {
    for (char c : row)
        s += c == 0 ? " " : c;
    s += "\n";
}

System.out.println(s);
```

Output:

```
XOX  
 O   
XOX
```

---

**Edit:** If you want the output to be spaced out, you could use

```
for (char[] row : board) {
    for (char c : row)
        s += c == 0 ? "  " : c + " ";
    s += "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
X O X 
  O   
X O X
```

Answer (score 0):

Have nested loops like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < board[0].length; j++)
    {
        System.out.print(board[i][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

The first print statement will add all the characters from one row together and then the next print statement, outside of the second loop, will append a newline.

Answer (score 0):

```
  for(int i=0; i< board.length; i++){
     for(int j=0; i< board[i].length; j++){
        System.out.print(""+board[i][j]);  //<- use print() here
      }
      System.out.println(); //<- use println() here
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  String[][] board = {{"X", "X","O"},{" ", "X", " "},{"O", "O", "X"}};
  for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < board[0].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(board[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```